# Is material UI DataGrid/XGrid support the IE 11?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Our team is trying to use material-UI DataGrid/XGrid to generate the tables.

But it looks the DataGrid and XGrid are not supporting IE 11 well.

Both of tables are showing blank page on IE 11:
https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/#mit-version

Does anyone has idea if we could use DataGrid/XGrid for IE 11 now?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Your question is more like if IE11 supports Reactjs because Material UI is a React UI framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At https://next.material-ui.com/getting-started/supported-platforms/ you will currently find the following:

---

#### IE 11

Material-UI provides **partial** supports for IE 11. Be aware of the following:

- Some of the components have no support. For instance, the new components, the data grid, the date picker.
- Some of the components have degraded support. For instance, the outlined input border radius is missing, the combobox doesn't remove diacritics, the circular progress animation is wobbling.
- The documentaton itself might crash.
- You need install the [legacy bundle](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#legacy-bundle).
- You might need to install polyfills. For instance for the [popper.js transitive dependency](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/browser-support/#ie11).

Overall, the library doesn't prioritize the support of IE 11 if it harms the most common use cases. For instance, we will close new issues opened about IE 11 and might not merge pull requests that improve IE 11 support.

v6 will completely remove the support of IE 11.

---

In particular, note the statement:

> Some of the components have no support. For instance, the new components, the **data grid**, the date picker.

`next.material-ui.com` is the documentation for the "next" version of Material-UI which is currently v5. The core components of Material-UI v4 fully support IE 11, but the statement about data grid (which is currently in the [lab](https://material-ui.com/components/about-the-lab/)) in the "next" documentation applies to the current lab version of data grid.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like they are not supporting IE, just try to open this url https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/ on IE!